# Non-Forcing and Independence

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Do there exists sentences which are independent of **ZFC**, cannot be shown to be independent through some method of forcing, and do not increase the consistency strength of **ZFC** (e.g. so Large Cardinal Axioms are out)?

If there does exist such a sentence, I would love to know a concrete example. One with a combinatorial flavor would be ideal.

Edit: Feel free to increase the consistency strength of **ZFC** (say **ZFC+ $\Delta$**) in the "meta-"sense (i.e. work where you want to work). Does there exist a "non-forcible" independent sentence that does not increase the consistency strength of **ZFC**?

Comment: We do not even know how to prove the consistency of $V\ne L$ with the restrictions you have listed.

Comment: Anyway, Harvey Friedman may have some examples. He has studied arithmetic statements ($\Pi^0_2$ or lower) that are independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, though usually his proofs of independence involve large cardinals. They necessarily involve non-standard models, since they involve disagreements at the arithmetic level.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: That's very interesting. Might you know of any literature on this topic? Or if there is some method by which one could prove that something is "not-forcably" independent?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I dont understand your comment about $V/neq L$, one can just add a Cohen real and get it. Or do you mean one cannot force $V=L$ from a model where it doesnt hold ? Also what about Godel's sentence, I dont think you can force that.

Comment: @Rene: I think that Andres meant that without forcing or large cardinals, we can't prove $V\neq L$ is even consistent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok, the question is about things that cannot be proved independent with forcing.

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/q/38727/6085).

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, and Godel's sentence increases consistency strength.